# Header with sticky position hide automatically

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have a sticky bar like this:

```
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The header looks like this: https://pastebin.com/j063TiCy

It's working but at one point, the menu auto-hides. I want it to stay displaying for the whole page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5tOc.jpg

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `position: fixed`?

Comment: Where is the related css of your header you have described in the link?

Comment: You probably have a container around your top part of the page. The sticky works in relation to its parent. So when that container goes out of the viewport the sticky element will follow it. So `body (or page-wrapper) > header-container > header` needs to be `body (or page-wrapper) > header`. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you shuould use `position:fixed; left:0;right:0; top:0;`

Comment: Welcome Nathan Cheval